Updating Java version from 8 to 17 on Eclipse 4.7 (Oxygen)
In my previous question I was suggested to update the Java version from 8 to 17 (or later).
I was given a 2017 Eclipse version (Oxygen, 4.7.0) as you can see below:

Currently Eclipse is using JavaSE-1.8 as the JRE System Library as you can see here:

and here:

and here:

So I visited Java SE 17 archive downloads and downloaded Windows x64 Compressed Archive, unzipped the archive and paste the content on my Desktop:

In order to update the JRE I went to Preferences > Installed JREs and tried to Add the newly downloaded JRE as a Standard VM but I get an error:

that is

Target is not a JDK root. System library was not found.

Note that I do not want to locally install a JVM on my computer.
How can I fix the issue?

You need a newer Eclipse version. It is unlikely a 7 year old Eclipse version can work with Java 17.  It probably won't even support Java 9, which radically changed the file layout of the JDK, which is probably why you get that "Target is not a JDK root" error.

A 2017 Eclipse would most likely be Eclipse 4.7 (Oxygen) which is now 7 years and 24 releases old and supports up to about Java 8 depending on the exact release. If the RCP you were given is a similar age it will probably needed updating to work with the latest Eclipse repositories and Java 17.

4.7.0 supports up to Java 8. So you either install the current Eclipse 2024-03 (4.31) and use Java 17 and current Eclipse repositories, or you stay with Eclipse Oxygen and switch to Eclipse repositories of a similar age which still work with Java 8.

@greg-449 The official website (https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation#Eclipse_4.7_.28Oxygen.29) for Eclipse 4.7 (Oxygen) says that: "A Java 8 or newer JRE/JDK is required to run all Oxygen packages based on Eclipse 4.7, including running the Installer." So... can I use Java 17 or not?

No you can't because you will need to tell Eclipse you want a Java 17 compliance level and it won't know what that is.

Usually new java version, new eclipse version.

I had to update the version of Eclipse to the latest version, as suggested in the comment box.
